# Issue posting API request from AWS Lambda with nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

completely beginner question here, but im stuck for hours, hope someone can help!

I'm building some thing over AWS API Gateway + Lambda, where I receive a POST request on AWS and I send some data to another API.
I'm using https from NodeJS (from examples i found here on stackoverflow) but it doesnt seem to be working...I'm testing by sending it to a webhook inbox in beeceptor

Could you give me some light?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    if(event.httpMethod == 'POST'){
        return pedido(event);
    }
};

var aid = '';
var cep = '';

const pedido = event => {
    let body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    var aid = body.cid;
    //var sku = body.items.id
    var cep = body.cep;
    callapi(cep,aid);
    console.log("teste cep ", body.cep);
    return{
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: body.cep,
            convid: aid
        })
       
    };
};

function callapi(cep,aid){
const https = require('https');
const data = JSON.stringify({
    message: cep,
    convid: aid,
    test: 123

});
console.log("data is ", data);
const options = {
  hostname: 'testbot.free.beeceptor.com',
  //port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
};

  console.log("code was here ");


var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
console.log('req:', req);
console.log('res:', res);
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);
  
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

console.log('req:', req);


req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
}
```

Comment: the console.logs inside this "var req = https.request(options, (res) => {" never show up to me, so it seems like its not going in that part

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one problem with your code:

The `callapi` function is making a request and this request is using a callback to notify you about a response. However, you are not waiting for it in your Lambda code and hence you won't see its response in your logs. Add appropriate `await`s or `Promise`s to it, so your code won't return before you've received a response.

The structure of your code could look similar to this:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  if (event.httpMethod === 'POST') {
    return await pedido(event);
  }
};

async function pedido(event) {
  // init vars...
  
  // wait for your API call
  await callapi(cep, aid);
  
  // then return a response
  return {...}
}

async function callapi(cep, aid) {
  // init vars like https and others...

  // then use a promise and resolve it when you receive the request's callback (= response) or an error
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      // handle response however you like ...

      // then resolve the promise when you're done
      resolve();
    });
    
    req.on('err', (e) => {
      // reject in case the request fails
      reject(e);
    });
  });
}
```

Does this solve your problem? If not, having some more logs of your method and a simplified code example would help a lot!

Comment: thank you for your help, will test this!!